# How can I post comments to other users' questions/answers without reputation?

Tags: discussion

I've gotten past this on stackexchange because as a developer I have more to say about programming, but I often run into superuser type issues and find the knowledge here to be quite handy as well.

In researching, the only way to comment here (for me) appears to be submitting another separate answer as a comment, but this is fail because the user you are trying to comment to may not get any notification. It is also fail because it is abusing the answer question privilege and people get downvoted for doing this. I come to superuser for help but find it incredibly hostile and difficult to use when I can't even reply to people.

If I can answer a question at 1 rep, surely I should be able to add something useful via comment to another answer, no?

Comment: Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Depending on what it is, it might be appropriate to suggest an edit on the other post.

Comment: **"In researching, the only way to comment here (for me) appears to be submitting another separate answer as a comment, but this is fail because the user you are trying to comment to may not get any notification."** - Comments submitted as answers are subject to be removed by the community.Comments should ONLY be submitted in the comment section, if you cannot actually answer the question without making a comment, don't submit an answer.In other words, if you cannot comment, don't submit comments.  If an answer contains a question, I never find it helpful, answers shouldn't generate questions.

Comment: I'd note enough SO reputation - so you get the association bonus(or su reputation! A single good answer would easily cover it) would let you comment . While a meta post gives the idea you have *some* clue, you have not earned enough rep for the cold unfeeling system to understand that.

Comment: Do some editing!

Answer (score 3):

As [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174) DavidPostill linked to said, you should write answers that don't require extra information from the original poster. I like to use the form "this problem can be caused by *thing* because *stuff* happens; you can fix it by doing *solution*." Having sources/references in such answers helps a lot. Alternatively, just wait until you have the 50 rep before making any comments. (Speaking here in that sense is a privilege, not a right.)

If there's something grammatically or syntactically wrong with an existing answer, edit it. **Do not edit alternative solutions into others' answers!** Such edits will likely be rejected because the change the meaning of the post; reviewers aren't expected to judge technical accuracy.

I noticed you almost have 200 rep at Stack Overflow. Once you hit that, you'll receive +100 (the association bonus) on your other sites, making you able to comment literally anywhere.